# How do I get rid of the console when writing GUI programs with gtk in C?

Tags: c, windows-xp, console, gtk

I'm following the tutorial:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/firstprograms/

It works but each time I double click on the executable,there is a console which I don't want it there.

How do I get rid of that console?

Platform: windows XP.

BTW I also have this trouble when right click on the icon:

```
GLib-WARNING **: g_main_context_check() called recursively from within a source's check() or prepare() member.
```

Is there anyone familiar with this?

Answer (score 5):

When you link, use the argument -mwindows

```
gcc -o simple simple.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-2.0` -mwindows
```

Comment: Thanks!Let me try if it works. What about the `GLib-WARNING` issue?

Comment: Seems it's not working for windows. Though I've installed gcc environment already.

Comment: No idea about that; as it's a warning, I'd probably just ignore it.

Comment: But there will be thousands of the same warning as long as I don't cancel right click on the icon.

Comment: It reports: `gcc: `pkg-config: No such file or directory`,`gcc: gtk+-2.0`: No such file or directory`

Comment: I was just copying from the tutorial you linked. Presumably you've successfully compiled it before? Just do what you already did and add the "-mwindows"

Comment: I'm using cmake to build, and it can't recognize the -mwindows switch: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -mwindows")`

Comment: It wouldn't be CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. I don't know CMAKE, but it would possibly be something like CMAKE_LXX_FLAGS (Look for "L")

Answer (score -1):

The console opens then an application outputs text (which perhaps was obvious). By default the application outputs text then an error occurs. Use **g_set_printerr_handler()** change that behaviour (into displaying an error dialog, writing to a file or whatever you want).

Comment: That's not the problem; on Windows, gcc builds console binaries by default, which open a console whether text is output or not. You have to link with the `-mwindows` switch to get a binary that doesn't open a console, as in @Matthew Talbert's answer.