# Preventing terminal window from popping up when launching program

Tags: c, windows, gcc, gtk

I am compiling this program on Windows, with gcc (MinGW) and GTK+:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void *destroy(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Initalize GTK+
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    // Create GTK+ window
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(destroy), NULL);

    // Show all widgets
    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    // Enter loop
    gtk_main();

    // Exit program
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and runs, but the problem is that when I launch the program, it launches in a terminal window before opening the GUI window.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of the console when writing GUI programs with gtk in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752479/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-console-when-writing-gui-programs-with-gtk-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

Add the `-mwindows` flag when compiling.

Comment: Which argument there corresponds to argc and which to argv?  Or how to map lpCmdLine to argc and argv?

Comment: Updated answer with a much more simple solution.

Comment: Thanks, I added `-mwindows` to the command line when I was linking (not compiling) the files, and now it works great