# How do I stop the Console Window from appearing when making system calls?

Tags: c, winapi, user-interface, console, gtk

I am using C and GTK+ for a gui project. For my project I have to make a lot systems calls. e.g  system("copy myfile urfile"); or system("mp3player -embed filename") etc. and whenever my program calls the system an annoying console window  appears and stays visible until the command is completely carried out. How do I hide that console window? Thanks.

NOTE: For my project I can use GTK+ , the C Standard Library , GLib, WinApi (not recommended) and system calls.

SCREENSHOT:
[image: annoying console window]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of the console when writing GUI programs with gtk in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752479/how-do-i-get-rid-of-the-console-when-writing-gui-programs-with-gtk-in-c)

Comment: Sorry, I clicked too fast. It's not a duplicate at all. Please excuse the close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `system()` to create a new process does this by first starting a new command interpreter, which then in turn executes the command passed to `system()`.

The command interpreter opens the console window.

Thus to avoid opening such a console windows you need to avoid starting the command interpreter. To do the latter try a function out of the `spawn` family (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20y988d2.aspx) or use the win32 api function `CreateProcess()` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425) to directly start your application.

A side effect on doing so might be, that your application starts faster and also uses less system resourses.

In fact the above mentioned solutions will not work for system calls which *explicitly need* a command interpreter as in one of your examples (`copy src dst`).

Comment: Why would he need a command interpreter for `copy myfile urfile` when `CopyFile("myfile","urfile",FALSE);` should work just fine? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Don't use platform-specific functions like CreateProcess see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GLib processes spawning functions](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) instead of platform-specific functions. For file copy you can use [g_file_copy](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-copy) from GIO (shipped with GTK) instead of calling the cp or copy command. This makes your code more portable too.